# Inline Form PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm designing an e-commerce site where I have no access to the server-side code at all. It's an off the shelf thing. Anyway, I despise forms with labels. They're the ugliest things on the planet.

I want form values which delete onfocus and reappear onblur etc. However, due to having no access to the PHP, I can't validate the form so it won't send when "Email Address" is typed in etc.

Is there any way around this without access to the PHP?

Comment: Javascript/jQuery could do this, but of course only if JS is enabled

Comment: ...and further to Pekka's comment, if the user doesn't have JS enabled and you've removed all the labels, how will they know what fields are what? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with CSS+Javascript

Position the Label over the textBox in JS so that if JS is disabled, the label will be somewhere else and hide it onFocus. 
This way your textBox are always empty by default.

You should also do form validation in JS.

Comment: You mean, use form values, hiding onfocus and validate using JS. But how can I make the label appear above the form and then validate using PHP if JS is disabled?

Comment: The label will have to appear by default (or with js disabled) over the form. If js is not disabled, you move it over the box (by modifying the CSS with JS).

You might also be interested in [html5 new markup](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

As for the PHP validation, JS or no JS changes barely nothing, it has to be done after submitting the form, server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have no access to the server, javascript is pretty much your only answer. You could get really clever and have a proxy or something that intercepts traffic and re-writes the webpage, but that would require access to the network of anyone who will be using this site.

The javascript solution will require the client to take some action (i.e. a greasemonkey script they have to install).

Comment: Can I do some kind of if statement to stop the form submitting if the value="Email Address"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want form values appear on onfocus event etc. it's ONLY possible throught javascript and has nothing to do with server side code.

If you want form validation, then this MUST be done on server side (PHP) and SHOULD be done in client side (javascript), for better user experience.

And what do you mean that you don't have access to source files? How can you modify even the client side then (other than for yourself)?

Comment: it's an off the shelf software. I have access to all HTML and CSS but no server side.